# How to run a specific maven test class from the terminal?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with junit tests classes. 
I want to run a tests in a specific class . how can i do that from the terminal ? 
for example i have a test spring junit test class named AccountServiceImplTest  under the package com.openmind.service.impl . how can i run all or individual junit tests declared in this test class . I dont want to use mvn clean test as this run all the tests within the project.
appreciate any help
thank you so much

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: mvn surefire:test -Dtest=com.openmind.primecast.service.impl.PrimecastAccountServiceImplTest shouldCreateAccount i tried this option however ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "shouldCreateAccount". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, proc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test

see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: yes it works . i tried like this in my case mvn -X  -Dtest=com.openmind.primecast.service.impl.PrimecastAccountServiceImplTest compile test to run a specific test mvn -X  -Dtest=com.openmind.primecast.service.impl.PrimecastAccountServiceImplTest#shouldCreateAccount compile test